# Corro todo lo que puedo/pueda?

Tags: subjuntivo

Do I have to use the subjunctive in this case?

> I run as much as I can

Which one is correct?

> *Corro todo lo que puedo.*

OR

> *Corro todo lo que pueda.*

Comment: Why should you use the subjunctive?

Comment: because I am not sure about how much I might be able to run but I'll do my best. So there's uncertainty about it and that's why I thought it might be the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [your comment](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26258/corro-todo-lo-que-puedo-pueda#comment43476_26258) I understand what your doubt is. The trick is that if you say

> Corro todo lo que puedo.

you are either stating that you are running right now ("I'm running as fast as I can"), or talking about something you usually do (and know about, as in "I usually run as fast as I can"). So as you know about your own limits, the sentence uses the indicative mood.

You need to talk in subjunctive when there is some uncertainty. If you change the example to

> Correré todo lo que pueda.

now you are talking about something yet to happen and don't know about (you still don't know your limits), so you use the subjuntive.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta! Después de contemplar la pregunta un poco me hubía occurrido la idea a lo que refieres aquí pero no estaba muy seguro pero ahora estoy!